# Assert fail with JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a class with an attribute I don't want to be null.

Si in the setter looks like this :

```
public void setFoo(String bar)
{
    if (bar == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Should not be null");
    foo = bar;
}
```

And in my JUnit test case, I would like to assert that if I do obj.setFoo(null), it will fail.
How can I do this?

Comment: have you tried `Assert.assertNotNull()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit4:

```
@Test(expected= IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testNull() {
   obj.setFoo(null);
}
```

JUnit3:

```
public void testNull() {
   try {
       obj.setFoo(null);
       fail("IllegalArgumentException is expected");
   } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
       // OK
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
@Test (expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void setFooTest(){
    myObject.setFoo(null);
}
```